# Ionic/Cordova AngularJS getting request header of $http

Tags: angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework

I want to get the $http cookie request header after a request but the $http only returns a response according to the AngularJS documentation. Here is the cookie I want to get:

[image]

I tried adding an interceptor but I couldn't see the cookie. Here is the output from my interceptor:

[image]

My interceptor and some settings:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
      return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
          console.log(config);
          return config;
        }
      };
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    //Remove text on back button
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false).text('&emsp;&emsp;');
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //Setting angularjs' $http to behave as url encoded parameters and request instead of JSON
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: tried that too, it's returning undefined

Comment: but do you gave ngCookies included in your project?

Comment: yes, tried using $cookies.get('JSESSIONID') inside the success callback of http but it is undefined..

Comment: what do you get if you ise getAll()

Comment: weird, I get this: Object {_ga: "GA1.1.1725476839.1445841661"}

Comment: __ga is google analytics cookie... mostly it means that server is setting http-only header, which is preventing you from getting cookies

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use cookies in a cordova app. There are quite a many other posts on the issue in Stackoverflow and the most recent info I found on [this blog](http://justbuildsomething.com/cordova-and-express-session/), where the issue is stated in these words:

> I honestly like everything about Cordova aside from the fact that you can’t use cookie based sessions.

In cordova you can though access session storage and localstorage, introduced by html5.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp introduces for example localstorage with words:

> HTML local storage, better than cookies.

http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/ has example code like this:

> Use this simple AngularJS service for setting and retrieving strings or objects easily:

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
       return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

> And to use this service, just inject the $localstorage service into a controller or run function:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ionic.utils'])

.run(function($localstorage) {

  $localstorage.set('name', 'Max');
  console.log($localstorage.get('name'));
  $localstorage.setObject('post', {
    name: 'Thoughts',
    text: 'Today was a good day'
  });

  var post = $localstorage.getObject('post');
  console.log(post);
});
```

Now, with this example in hand, you can do something similar to:

```
$localstorage.set('sessionId', 'yourSessionIdGoesHere');
```

and read

```
$localstorage.get('sessionId');
```

Comment: Why is that using chrome in desktop, cookies are also undefined?

Comment: Is the cookie marked httponly (tick on column 'http' in cookies tab)? That means http protocol takes care of the cookies and javascript does not have access on it.

Comment: httpOnly prevents malicious use of cookies, http protocol takes care of sending it back to server, you don't need to bother about that.

Comment: the cookie is not httponly, i'm using the cookies for other purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind me asking, why do you want to read the JSESSIONID on the client side?

I can imagine that you would want to send it with every subsequent request, but that's automatically done for you if you use withCredentials = true.

Comment: Since I'm scraping data, I'm storing the JSESSIONID when the user successfully logged in. After every request, I compare the new cookie to the stored cookie to check if the user session is expired. I do it this way because I'm scraping data from a third party website.

Comment: OK, so usually when the user is logged out (session expired) on the server side, your request will be redirected back to i.e. the login page. You could then check if that has happened and log the user back in and your cookie will be automatically updated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site does not redirect the user to the login page. One of the biggest problems. I tried doing other methods like checking the HTTP status but it does not provide a session expired status. My last bet is to parse the whole page source and check the document if it contains "session expired" text but this will be too dirty.

Comment: Well if that's the only way to check if the session has expired, then just go for that option. What I would recommend is that you create your own service that does the web scraping, so if the 3rd party ever changes their session expired page, you can just update your service immediately and your users won't have to wait for an app update.

Comment: I had that in mind. I need to test it first because of its additional network load.